# How i get selected item from combo box to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a combobox in my html view and  a controller, my requirement is to pass selected item text from html view to controller at the same time upload an image to server.`upload_control/do_upload` method for uploading image to server

```html
 <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload_control/do_upload');?>
               <input type="file" id="bt_chooseImage" name="userfile"/><br>
               
                 <select name="category_images" id="combo_category">
                
                    <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
                 
               </select>
            
<input type="submit" id="bt_uploadImage" value="Submit"/><br>
```

Please note I already used a

```html
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload_control/do_upload');?>
```

already checked on `onchange="this.form.submit()"`

when i use onchange file uploading not working

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `$val = $_POST['category_images']`

Comment: not solved my problem

Comment: in onchange function call AJAX call to send data of your Form

Comment: @Abdulla your first comment is working well. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple can access that by using

```
$val = $_POST['category_images'];
```

Or in CI method

```
$val = $this->input->post('category_images');
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line :

```
<select name="category_images" id="combo_category">
```

to

```
<select name="category_images" id="combo_category" onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

Then in your controller upload_control/do_upload, you can get the selected value using :

```
echo $this->input->post('category_images');
```

For processing the uploaded file, you may use Codeigniter File Upload library.